# Lock UIScrollView on specific page (pagingEnabled)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView with paging enabled, and that works fine.

Now I want to 'lock' the UIScrollView on a specific page, prevent the user from scrolling to the next or previous page. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
   if(currentPage == 4)
      [scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO]; // when the page is "4", scroll will be locked
//or
   [scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:false];    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just disable the interaction

```
scrollView.interactionEnabled = NO;
```

Unless you want interaction within that page?